# Can I make vb.net run in Compile Time

Tags: vb.net, time, compilation, runtime

Basically I am creating a program and would like it to run in compile time as opposed to the standard run time, I would like to know how, if possible, please. 
Thanks

Comment: That's extremely vague.  Project + Properties, Compile tab, click Build Events and press F1.

Comment: You design in design time, compile in compile time and run in run time. There is no such thing like running in compile time.

Comment: oh :/ oh well that ideas scrapped then, thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

You would need to change your build system to, having compiled the VB code into an executable, run that executable.

But without details of the build system you are using, and what you are implementing with this code it is hard to be more specific.

Comment: I am using Visual Basic 2010, and am in a Windows Form Application. The programme has variables which are created during running and from what I gather to be able to use these after creation my project will need to run in compile time.

Comment: @GeorgeColdham: A post build operation is the simplest starting point and doesn't mean leaving VS. However a GUI won't fit well (the GUI will be shown), I would expect to only consider console applications.